# JQuery .animate() with Direction That Created from an Array of Objects, But

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, animation

I want to create a continuous animation effects using the JQuery `.animate()` with direction that created from an array. This is what I did successfully so far:

```
var animation = [{"top":80},{"left":130},{"top":200},{"left":0},{"top":0}];

$.each(animation, function(i) {
    $('div').animate(animation[i], 1000);
});
```

But then, I want to save the array in each of the element attribute like this:

```
<div data-animation='[{"top":80},{"left":130},{"top":200},{"left":0},{"top":0}]'></div>
<div data-animation='[{"top":50},{"left":-30},{"top":100},{"left":80},{"top":75}]'></div>
<div data-animation='[{"top":10},{"left":-30},{"top":100}]'></div>
```

... so I hope I can animate multiple elements with different direction. But I don't know how to convert the attribute value into an array of objects (I hope I can do this without a plugin):

```
$('div').each(function() {

    var animation = $(this).data('animation'), // How to convert this into an array?
        $animatedbox = $(this);

    $.each(animation, function(i) {
        $animatedbox.animate(animation[i], 1000);
    });

});
```

**Here's a demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wthLR/

Comment: I dont see your problem. I changed your fiddle and it's working. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wthLR/10/)

Comment: Weird. It's not working previously, considering that the value of the attribute is a string, not an array. But thank you @Felipe Fonseca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var $div = $(this);
    var animation = eval($div.attr('data-animation'));
    $.each(animation, function(i) {
        $div.animate(animation[i], 1000);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wthLR/12/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').each(function() {

    var animation = eval($(this).attr('data-animation')),
        $animatedbox = $(this);

    $.each(animation, function(i) {
        $animatedbox.animate(animation[i], 1000);
    });

});
```

This works

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if you dont want to use the evil `eval` function:

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var $div = $(this);
    var data = $div.data('animation').replace(/[[\]]/g,'');
    var dataArray = data.split(',');
    var animations = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var trimBrackets = dataArray[i].replace(/[{\}]/g,'');
        var keyValues = trimBrackets.split(':');
        var key = keyValues[0].replace(/\'/g, '');
        var value = parseInt(keyValues[1], 10);

        animations[i] = {};
        animations[i][key] = value;
    }

    $.each(animations, function (i, v) {
        $div.animate(v, 1000);
    });
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/tZMmy/